# sequelize aggregate group by not working as I want

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I want to fetch Votes Info with relations in a group according to audioId, but my code not working as aspected. `'user. id'` break the group, and showing one by one vote.

what is the problem with my code? and how to group with only audioId and also fetch related Data

```
  try {
        const votes = await globalVotes.findAll({
            group: ['audioId', 'mediaType', 'audio.id', 'user.id'],

            attributes: [
                'audioId',
                'mediaType',
                [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('totalVote')), 'total_vote'],
                [Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('voterEmail')), 'latest_email'],
                [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('voteCount')), 'total_vote_count'],
                [Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('vottingNum')), 'latest_number'],
                [Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('globalVotes.user_Id')), 'latest_user'],
                [
                    Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('globalVotes.updatedAt')),
                    'latest_time',
                ],
            ],
            include: [
                {
                    model: Audio,
                    attributes: ['aTitle', 'aImage', 'audioFolderId'],
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: AudioFolder,
                            attributes: ['folderName'],
                        },
                    ],
                    group: ['audioFolderId.id'],
                },
                {
                    model: User,
                    attributes: ['fullName'],
                },
            ],

            order: [[Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('totalVote')), 'DESC']],
            raw: true,
            nest: true,
        });
        console.log(votes);
        res.status(200).render('admin/chart/audio/index', {
            title: 'Manage Audio Votes',
            votes,
        });
```

hope i get some info,

Comment: You're trying to group by a user id and at the same time to get an aggregation with it `Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('globalVotes.user_Id')), 'latest_user'`. Remove either of them in order to query be more consistent.

Comment: And, of course, Sequelize is not so suitable for complex aggregations, it's more about CRUD operations and loading associations.

Comment: @Anatoly then what is the solution ?

Comment: You should choose either you want to calculate `Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('globalVotes.user_Id')), 'latest_user'` or to group by `user.id`